# Unexpected JVM terminated. Exit code=13 Error while starting STS 3.9?

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite

Problem

I was able to start STS yesterday but unexpected error is coming today.

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/home/jalaj/Java/Java8/jre1.8.0_144/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms40m
-Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10
-Xverify:none
-Xmx1200m
-jar /home/jalaj/Downloads/sts-bundle/sts-3.9.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/jalaj/Downloads/sts-bundle/sts-3.9.0.RELEASE/STS
-name STS
--launcher.library /home/jalaj/Downloads/sts-bundle/sts-3.9.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133/eclipse_1624.so
-startup /home/jalaj/Downloads/sts-bundle/sts-3.9.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 378017
-product org.springsource.sts.ide
-vm /home/jalaj/Java/Java8/jre1.8.0_144/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms40m
-Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10
-Xverify:none
-Xmx1200m
-jar /home/jalaj/Downloads/sts-bundle/sts-3.9.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
```

My Analysis

1)I have checked my system JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME path,javac and java version and have made changes in STS.ini after it failed to start but still I am not getting any result.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/jalaj/Java/Java8/jdk1.8.0_144

echo $JRE_HOME
/home/jalaj/Java/Java8/jre1.8.0_144

jalaj@jalaj-X540YA:~$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_144

jalaj@jalaj-X540YA:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

My STS.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
 --launcher.library   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
/home/jalaj/Java/Java8/jre1.8.0_144/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms40m
-Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10
-Xverify:none
-Xmx1200m
```

> Can anyone guide me how to resolve this issue.I have researched various threads about this error but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your JAVA_HOME points to a 32bit JDK installation whereas the STS installation that you are trying to run is a 64bit installation. Make sure you have a 64bit JDK installed and configured.

In addition to that I also vaguely remember that you have the -vm option in the ini file as the first one in that file. But I am not sure if that is really related to the problem.